# Grakn installation on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, vaticle-typedb

Running Ubuntu in an Oracle VM VirtualBox on WIN 10 and attempting to install and run Grakn. Not experienced with Linux or Java.

Ran ./grakn server start. Result was:

```
“Starting Storage.......................FAILED!
Unable to start Storage
Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under 'logs' directory.”
```

Logs directory were:

```
“2018-05-21 23:1551,955 [main] INFO ai.grakn.engine.GraknConfig - Project directory in use: /home/e-maps/Downloads/grakn-dist-1.2.0”

“2018-05-21 23:1551,963 [main] INFO ai.grakn.engine.GraknConfig - Configuration file in use: /home/e-maps/Downloads/grakn-dist-1.2.0/conf/grakn.properties”
```

Comment: Have you run 'grakn server status'? What is the result?

Comment: it look like there is insufficient memory. Have you tried to expand the VM assigned memory?

Comment: Can you make sure you have Java 8 (and not Java 7, 9 or 10) installed. Grakn only supports Java 8 for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your java version, try updating/installing it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```